# How do I create a POST Azure Function that can perform model binding on the body?

Tags: post, azure-functions

With GET, I can just put a parameter in the function definition:

```
[FunctionName("GetKittenById")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "GetKittenById/{kittenId}")] HttpRequest req,
    string kittenId,
    ILogger log) { ... }
```

I want to do the same thing with POST. However if I add a parameter and do this:

```
[FunctionName("CreateKitten")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "POST", Route = "CreateKitten")] HttpRequest req,
    Kitten kitten,
    ILogger log) { ... }
```

Then my function throws an error when it's POST'd to.

> [07/03/2019 16:17:00] An unhandled host error has occurred.
>   [07/03/2019 16:17:00] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:
>   'CreateKitten' can't be invoked from Azure WebJobs SDK. Is it
>   missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?.

I can't find on google how to do this. I assume there is built-in binding because when you do a GET you can specify if you want JSON or XML. I want to do the same thing in reverse and let the framework handle it in case they post JSON or XML.

Is there a way to automatically do this or do I have to start poking around in the HttpRequest and deserializing content?

---

I've found that you can replace the `HttpRequest req` with `Kitten kitten` and it will do model binding, but I need to keep access to the `HttpRequest` to be able to read some custom authentication headers.

Is there a way to get both of these without rolling my own? Checking to see if they've sent JSON or XML and writing my own code to do the model binding is a pain just so that I can retrieve the http context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by replacing HttpRequest to the type you want to in the HttpTrigger binding itself like this,

[image]

If you also want to get the header from HttpRequest then add the type HttpRequest as another parameter and read header values like below. Here I have added a header "custom-header" during the POST and reading it from from the HttpRequest object. Request Body will automatically be parsed to Kitten type

[image]

Comment: How do I access the headers if I do this though?

Comment: simply add another parameter of type HttpRequest. I have updated the answer as well

Comment: By default, the functions use `HttpRequestMessage` rather than `HttpRequest`, as `HttpRequest` is part of ASP.NET, but that doesn't work. This does though. Thanks.